# PDFView Display image Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

In my application, I want to have the capability to zoom on images. I have tried with IKImageView but it is causing some problem on 10.5. Specifically after the first image, everything shows up as white.  Since Preview app is able to display images(png,jpg), I was thinking of using PDFView. But the problem is, when I pass the path of the image to the PDFDocument, it throws an exception. It says, PDF header not found. Is it possible to display .jpg, .png files using PDFView ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible to display .jpg, .png files using PDFView ?.*

No. A PDFView is for PDF files.  If you want to show other image formats, use an NSImageView.

Comment: Or an IKImageView, with investigation into “everything show[ing] up as white”.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a UIWebView, which can display PDFs, JPGs, PNGs and various other things.

Comment: Read question properly before answer. Q relates to Cocoa not for iPhone sdk.

Comment: I believe the same would apply on the Mac, using WebView instead of UIWebView.